# Is there a way to split Google Slides table using Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I have a long table that can't fit into one slide of Google Slides. I can split it manually, but I want to use Apps Script to make it faster.

The idea is that when certain rows of the table reach amounts to maximum height, the rest of the table is cut and pasted to the next slide. Is there a way to do so?

I have tried to use Slides API to get Page Elements and retrieve its row height (in EMU), but the Page Elements does not update every time the table dimension changes.

If I check the height, add one row, then check the height again, it will still return the same number unless I run the checking separately.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.